# Is the following claim true: "every ordinal has the empty set as one of its elements"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Since we can encode every element as a set, suppose that we consider only sets in which every element is also a set.
My question is, **is it true that every ordinal has the empty set as one of its elements?**

The proof I was thinking of:
Suppose not. Let A be an ordinal which does not contain the empty set as an element.
Take $b_1 \in A$. $b_1 \neq \emptyset$ Then by definition of an ordinal we should have $b_2 \in b_1$ and by the same argument we will have $b_3 \in b_2$,...,$b_{n-1} \in b_n$,... so we get an infinite decreasing sequence of elements in $A$, contradicting the fact that $A$ is a well ordered set. am I right? seems suspicious to me since I haven't encountered such a claim...

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: $0$ doesn't have the empty set as an element.

Comment: It's a thankless task to point this out, but strictly speaking ordinals don't have members -- it is the set-theoretic representations of ordinals (in von Neumann's now canonical scheme) that have elements. Just saying ....

Comment: Oh, @Peter, really...?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo "the ordinals" are a mathematical structure. There is a natural way so "see" them in sets just like there is a natural way to "see" the integers as sitting inside that set theoretic representation, but the ordinals as a structural property are distinct from the objects that manifest that structural property. Furthermore, depending on how precisely you define things, there might be multiple sets in a given model of ZFC that satisfy the ordinal structural property. You can introduce an undefined object $\xi$ that isn't and just stick it into your set theory.

Comment: Doing this has a bunch of weird consequences, but one of them is that $\{\xi\}$ can form the basis for the ordinals in exactly the same way that $\{\}$ does in the usual representation.

Answer (score 5):

This is false, but only for trivial reasons: The empty set itself is an ordinal.

However, if the ordinal is non-empty, then the empty set is indeed one of its elements. Your proof is correct, but it may be better to use well-foundedness directly: Your ordinal $\alpha$ is well-ordered by $\in$, so it has a least element (here we use that $\alpha$ is non-empty). Call it $b$. The point is that ordinals are transitive, so $b$ is a subset of $\alpha$. If $c$ is any element of $b$, then $c\in b\cap\alpha$, contradicting minimality. So $b$ is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof starts with "Take $b_1\in A$". You can't do that in general.
And the case where you can't gives you an ordinal not having $\emptyset$ as element ...

Apart from that: $\emptyset$ is an ordinal and the class of ordinals is ordered by $\in$. Hence for any ordinal $A\ne\emptyset$ we have either $A\in\emptyset$ (which is absurd)  or indeed $\emptyset \in A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!