# Given that α is an ordinal number and β ⊆ α has the property (∀x < y)(x ∈ β) ⇒ y ∈ β for every y ∈ α. I need to prove that β = α

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

A set $S$ is said to be transitive if $x ⊆ S$ for every $x ∈ S$.

A total order $≤$ on a set $S$ is said to
be a well-ordering if for every non-empty subset $A ⊆ S$, there exists an element $m ∈ A$ such that
$m ≤ x$    $∀x ∈ A.$

An ordinal number is a set that is transitive and is well-ordered by the relation
$α ≤ β ⇔ α ∈ β$ or $α = β$
or equivalently
$α < β ⇔ α ∈ β$.

**Now given that $α$ is an ordinal number and $β ⊆ α$ has the property
$(∀x < y)(x ∈ β) ⇒ y ∈ β$ for every $y ∈ α$. I need to prove that $β = α$.**

Here is my proof:

Suppose, in order to get a contradiction, that $\beta\ne \alpha​$ .Then as $\beta\subseteq\alpha​$, we have that $\alpha-\beta\ne \emptyset​$ and hence $\alpha - \beta​$ is a non-empty subset of the ordinal number $\alpha​$. By well-orderedness of the ordinal $\alpha​$, there exists an element $x\in \alpha-\beta​$ such that $\forall y\in \alpha-\beta, x\le y​$

Now consider any $\lambda\in \alpha​$ such that $\lambda<x​$ (Here is a possible problem which I have specified below). As if $\lambda\in \alpha-\beta​$, then $x​$ is not the least element of $\alpha-\beta​$ which contradicts to the fact that $\forall y\in \alpha-\beta, x\le y​$, there must be $\lambda\notin \alpha-\beta​$ and hence $\lambda\in \beta​$.

But then as we have $\lambda<x​$ and $\lambda\in \beta​$, by the property, $x\in\beta​$, contradicts the fact that $x\in \alpha-\beta​$.

Thus it cannot be that $\beta\ne \alpha​$. Thus...

I have come up with the above proof but I realised that **it might be not possible that there exists $\lambda\in \alpha​$ such that $\lambda<x​$**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=\emptyset\iff\emptyset\not\in\beta$. This is because $x$ is the least element of $\alpha$ that isn't in $\beta$, and $\emptyset$ is the least element of $\alpha$. However, if the property is true of $\beta$, then $\emptyset$ is in $\beta$ because the antecedent is vacuously true for $y=\emptyset$. Therefore the property itself asserts that $\emptyset\in\beta$.

Therefore we know that $\emptyset\in\beta$ and $x\neq\emptyset$. Therefore $x$ has elements, and so there is a $\lambda<x$.

Comment: You can't use expressions like $x< \beta$ unless you've already shown $\beta$ is an ordinal. The original question does not assume that.

Comment: @PropositionX I've amended my statement. $\beta=x$, and so $\beta\leq x$ holds but not $\beta<x$. That was supposed to be an intuitive comment though, and has no bearing on the proof I wrote.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that $\beta$ isn't an ordinal and have been assuming it was.

Comment: @StellaBiderman If possible, may I please ask you to gather your thoughts again and provide a full proof for the question? I am really confused by our previous discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @StellaBiderman What I need to prove is exactly that $\beta =\alpha$. How can you put that in you assumption in your 'if' part.

Comment: @PropositionX see my edited answer. My previous one was predicated upon the assumption that $\beta$ was an ordinal.

Comment: May I please ask how can we see that $x=\emptyset$ iff $\emptyset \notin \beta$, and why we cannot have $\emptyset \notin \beta$?

Comment: If y = 0 then (∀x < y)(x ∈ β) is vacuously true. Hence 0 ∈ β and so the x in PropositionX's proof cannot be 0.

Comment: @DavidHartley Now I am quite confusing. If you have fully understood may I ask for a full proof? Thanks so much!

Comment: @PropositionX I'm sorry that I misunderstood the problem and got so turned around. The answers to both your questions are in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have understand. But for a last question, how can we be able to take $y=\emptyset$? May I please ask see that for any ordinal, the empty set is always its element?

Comment: @PropositionX see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514915/is-the-following-claim-true-every-ordinal-has-the-empty-set-as-one-of-its-elem

Comment: You defined an ordinal as well-ordered and transitive.  Let $\alpha$ be a non-empty ordinal. Being well-ordered it must have a least element, say b. If b is non-empty then it has an element c and, by transitivity, c is an element of $\alpha$. But c < b, which contradicts the minimality of b. Hence b must be empty.  Every ordinal is either empty or has the empty set as its least element..