# Proof that the collection of ordinal set is well ordered from J.L Krivine book

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

I have an issue with a proof given "Théorie axiomatique des ensembles" by J.L Krivine.

Ordinal definition given of $\alpha$:

1. $"x \in y"$ defines a strict, total, well-foundedness relation R in $\alpha$
2. $x \in \alpha \Rightarrow x \subset \alpha$

We are trying to prove:

> Given two ordinal sets $\alpha$ and $\beta$, one of these cases is
> true: $\alpha \in \beta$ or $\beta \in \alpha$ or $\alpha = \beta$

The proof starts by considering $\xi = \alpha \cap \beta$

The sketch of the proof is:

$\xi \: initial \: segment \: of \: \alpha \Rightarrow \xi = \alpha \: or \: \xi \in \alpha$

$\xi \: initial \: segment \: of \: \beta \Rightarrow \xi = \beta \: or \: \xi \in \beta$

4 cases are studied. The last case $\xi \in \alpha$ and $\xi \in \beta$ is excluded because it will lead to $\xi \in \xi$ (impossible for ordinals)

My question is: how do we know $\xi \ne \emptyset$ ? Why two random ordinal sets have a common element ? Or does the proof holds if $\xi = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Where does the proof uses that $\xi\neq\varnothing$?

Comment: If $\xi = \emptyset$ then would it still be an initial segment of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Is the empty set a subset of $\alpha$?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of $\alpha$ but it does not prove it is an element of $\alpha$, does it ?
Every initial segment of $\alpha$ should be an element of $\alpha$, but is $\emptyset$ an element of every ordinal?

Comment: Is $\varnothing$ a transitive set? Is $\in$ a well-order of it?

Comment: I agree with you $\emptyset$ is an ordinal. But it does not prove it is an element of every ordinal ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I may have an answer to my question. Thanks @Asaf for pointing me to the right direction.
According to a comment in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514915/is-the-following-claim-true-every-ordinal-has-the-empty-set-as-one-of-its-elem), if an ordinal is not the emptyset, it contains the emptyset.
So, if $\xi$ is the emptyset, it is still an initial segment of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ considering none of them is an emptyset. If $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is the emptyset, the theorem we are trying to prove is trivial.